How to set fields in documents dynamically
In my program I need to store user messages and I would like the messages in the document to be stored in the following way, so that the time of message was the name of the field in the document, and the text of the message is the value of this field:
Document1:
timeOfMsg: messegeText
timeOfNextMsg: messegeText
...

I have a structure:
type MsgStr struct {
    Id   string    `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Time time.Time `bson:"time,omitempty"`
    Data string    `bson:"text,omitempty"`
}

I need it to set the time value from the data structure as the name of the field in the document and for one document to contain several messages.
I know how to do it without a structure:
insertResult, err := podcastsCollection.InsertOne(ctx, bson.D{{msg.time.String(), msg.Data}})

but then I will have a document for each message, and I need all the user's messages to be in one.

InsertOne returns the ID of the inserted document, use it to add the new message with an update:
insertResult, err := podcastsCollection.InsertOne(ctx, bson.D{
    {msg.time.String(), msg.Data},
})

podcastsCollection.UpdateOne(ctx,
    bson.D{{"_id": insertResult.InsertedID}},
    bson.D{{$set: {newMsg.time.String(), newMsg.Data}}},
)

